# Rails 6 Route Error undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

Getting this error with some of my routes.
undefined local variable or method `export_on_demand_dictionary_processor_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000002ada0
Did you mean?  export_on_demand_dictionary_processor_index_path

How do I fix this error without adding 'index' to all the route paths?

Error happens on the url path.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "<%= export_on_demand_dictionary_processor_path %>",
      data: $('#export_params_input').val() + '&' + $.param({'build_request_id' : $("#build_request_id").val()}),
      success: function(data, text_status, xhr) {
        window.location.href = data["new_href"];
        $("#load_build_section :input").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#export_progress_message").hide();
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        $("#load_build_section :input").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#export_progress_message").html("Export failed. (HTTP " + xhr.status + ")");

      }
    })
```

This is what my route.rb looks like.

```
resources :dictionary_processor, :as  => :dictionary_processor, :only => [] do
  collection {
    get 'import';
    get 'propose_on_demand';
    post 'run_import';
    get 'propose_build';
    post 'export_on_demand';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `resources` to `resource` or `dictionary_processor` to `dictionary_processors`. Singular and plural in names are important in rails.

Just be careful because the controller name will change to plural.
Before and after the change, you can check your routes with a command to see what has changed

```
rails routes
```

Comment: collection has to be plural, to the best of my knowledge, so 
export_on_demand_dictionary_processors_path

Comment: Thank you changing dictionary_processor to plural, dictionary_processors worked!